# Импорт проекта из Eclipse в Android Studio

Tags: android, java, gradle

Здравствуйте!

Есть проект на `Eclipse`, который нужно импортировать в `Android Studio`, пользуясь [этой инструкцией](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html). Получаю вот такую ошибку:

[image]

**Build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':appcompat_v7')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: Все написано в сообщении об ошибке. Скачайте Gralde версии 1.12, потом нажмите на "Gradle Settings" в этом сообщении, и укажите ему путь к тому, что скачали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился сам собой.

Создал проект в `Eclipse`, после этого открыл `Android Studio`**>File>Import** 
И все заработало.

Comment: "...выключить, включить пробовали?" (c) IT Crowd =)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Либо нужно поменять строку в gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Это

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip
```

Поменять на это

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

Comment: Это все при условии, что при импорте выполнился 4 пункт из инструкции

4. In the following dialog, leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK. (You do not need to specify the Gradle home.)

Comment: не помогло

Comment: @Garf1eld при импорте в студию точно был указан именно build.gradle?